# How to find the x-axis intersections/zeroes of a parametrized integral?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerical-integration

Consider the situation with this functions,

```
 F[mm_, q_] :=  NIntegrate[(q/2) * (x Tanh[π x]) *( ( (Coth[π q Sqrt[x^2 + mm] ]
                            )/Sqrt[ x^2 + mm] - Coth[π x])/x,
                {x, 0, ∞}] + (1/2) Tan[Sqrt[mm] π ]   ;

Plot[ F[mm, 2], {mm, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking at the graph it is clear that the function has roots in the range of $mm \in [0,1]$. But I am unable to use any of the root finding commands to get those numbers! Why are they not working here?

---

Also what are those vertical lines that the Mathematica is plotting here?

Comment: Try changing the lhs of the function definition to `F[mm_?NumericQ, q_]`, then use something like `FindRoot[F[mm, 2], {mm, 0.1}]`. See the [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/57) answer on the [what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) question.

Comment: p.s. just in case, vertical line is a plotting atrtifact and can be fixed by `Exclusions` or: `, RegionFunction -> (Abs[#2] < 5 &)` for example.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! So what do those vertical lines indicate? Can you kindly write the full command - as in where in the "Plot" function do I insert that?

Comment: Plot[ F[mm, 2], {mm, 0, 1} , RegionFunction -> (Abs[#2] < 5 &)]

Comment: @Kuba It removes the vertical line . But what does it really do mathematically?

Comment: @user6818 Mathematica does not know if there is a singularity or something so it is assuming there is a continuity, and it joins the points. Try plotting `Tan[x]`. This option works this way: there are points above `5` and below `-5` but our `RegionFunction` cuts them out  (`#2` stands for `y`) in context of plotting and will not try to join the outlayers, it knows there is something above. Am I clear? Because this comment looks like a mess :P

Comment: @Kuba But is there a way to ask Mathematica is there is a singularity there? Like is there a way in which Mathematica can be asked to find out divergences in a function in a given interval?

Comment: On example of `Tan`: `NSolve[1/Tan[x] == 0 && .1 < x < 2, x]`, or `FindRoot`.